# Add body to ClientRequest on Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I would like to use ClientRequest with Electron. I want to add a body to my request, but I see no information about `body` in the documentation.

My request object:

```
  const requestApi = {
    method,
    headers,
    protocol: process.env.API_PROTOCOL,
    hostname: process.env.API_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.API_PORT,
    path: `${process.env.API_PATH}${slug}`,
    body,
  };
```

And my request:

```
request.on('response', data => {
  console.log('---------------------');
  console.log(data);

  data.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log(chunk);
  });
  data.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });

  if (data.statusCode === 200) {
    event.sender.send('api-response');
  }
});

request.end();
```

When I console.log(data), the data is an empty array `data: []`.

Can anyone help me ? :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ClientRequest](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request) is a [Writable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams). The way to send body data to a Writable Stream is to use [`.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) and [`.end()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_end_chunk_encoding_callback). You can see these functions in the API documentation: [`ClientRequest.write()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request#requestwritechunk-encoding-callback) and [`ClientRequest.end()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request#requestendchunk-encoding-callback). The argument `chunk` is where your data should go.

In your example, that might look like this:

```
const requestApi = {
  method,
  headers,
  protocol: process.env.API_PROTOCOL,
  hostname: process.env.API_HOSTNAME,
  port: process.env.API_PORT,
  path: `${process.env.API_PATH}${slug}`,
};

const request = new ClientRequest(requestApi);

request.on('response', data => { /* ... */ });

request.end(body);
```